# What is right way showing virtual entitys field value which computing from service

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony3.x

I have an entity "File" and i want to show boolean value of existing related file in filesystem. For checking existence need to use my DirectoriesManager service which can detect it uses this File entity. What is the right way of configuring ListMapper for this task or it can be solved only by rewriting some sonata templates?
So, what i made:

**config.yml**

```
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    globals:
        container: '@service_container'
```

**My Sonata Admin class**

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('exist', null, [
            'template' => 'AdminBundle:Files:exist.html.twig'
        ]);
}
```

**And my template exist.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}

{% set value = container.get('dirs_manager').entityFileExist(object) %}

{% if value %}
    {% set text = 'label_type_yes'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') %}
{% else %}
    {% set text = 'label_type_no'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') %}
{% endif %}

{% if  value %}
    {% set class = 'label-success' %}
{% else %}
    {% set class = 'label-danger' %}
{% endif %}

<span class="label {{ class }}">{{ text }}</span>
{% endblock %}
```

Where service DirectoriesManager has alias dirs_manager.

I know that in Yii2  can configure GridView widget columns with callback for all models that shows any value. May be i can make something like in ListMapper?

Comment: Add what you have tried to the question.

Comment: @svgrafov my fault, please see updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add listener callback for doctrine's postLoad event. And inside that callback would use the service and set corresponding boolean entity's value.